# mergepythonclient 0.2.1 Accounting returns UNSUPPORTED_OPERATION when creating a payment to Xero

Tags: python, sdk

I am trying to use the Merge Python Client (https://pypi.org/project/mergepythonclient/) to create a Payment that goes to Xero accounting software.

I have successfully linked Xero with Merge and I can view existing payments in the Xero Demo Company via the Merge SDK.

My code is in a file called `payments.py` and the following are the contents of the file.

```py
import json

import merge
from merge.client import Merge
from pprint import pprint

# Configure Client
merge_client = Merge(api_key="YOUR_API_KEY", account_token="YOUR_ACCOUNT_TOKEN")

# Create a Payment
create_payment = merge_client.accounting.payments.create(
    model=merge.resources.accounting.PaymentRequest(
        id="aaa123de-cbae-470a-a8f8-bcbc119e0390",
        contact="a6e00e18-ade7-4fbf-8b4f-3a5c2c983bbb",
        transaction_date="2023-08-02T10:00:00Z",
        total_amount=396,
    )
)

pprint(json.loads(create_payment), indent=2)
```

The `id` is a random id string. The `contact` is a contact id for an existing contact in Xero.

However, when I try to use the Merge SDK and the above code to send a Payment to Xero, I get the following error:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\nda\PycharmProjects\XeroDemo\create_payments.py", line 11, in <module>
    create_payment = merge_client.accounting.payments.create(
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\nda\.virtualenvs\XeroDemo\Lib\site-packages\merge\resources\accounting\resources\payments\client.py", line 150, in create
    raise ApiError(status_code=_response.status_code, body=_response_json)
merge.core.api_error.ApiError: status_code: 400, body: {'warnings': [], 'errors': [{'source': None, 'title': 'Unsupported Operation', 'detail': 'Merge does not yet support this operation for the provided integration.', 'problem_
type': 'UNSUPPORTED_OPERATION'}]}
```

Any assistance to resolve this will be greatly appreciated.